# Как сделать чтобы когда программа не может расшифровать строку и за ключа программа выводила , что то типа не верный ключ

Tags: java, android

Код ошибки

///

```
D/AndroidRuntime: Shutting down VM
E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
    Process: com.example.myapplication, PID: 3901
    java.lang.IllegalStateException: Could not execute method for android:onClick
        at androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatViewInflater$DeclaredOnClickListener.onClick(AppCompatViewInflater.java:402)
        at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:4756)
        at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:19749)
        at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:739)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:135)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5221)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:899)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:694)
     Caused by: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372)
        at androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatViewInflater$DeclaredOnClickListener.onClick(AppCompatViewInflater.java:397)
        at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:4756) 
        at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:19749) 
        at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:739) 
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95) 
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:135) 
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5221) 
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372) 
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:899) 
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:694) 
     Caused by: org.jasypt.exceptions.EncryptionOperationNotPossibleException
        at org.jasypt.encryption.pbe.StandardPBEByteEncryptor.decrypt(StandardPBEByteEncryptor.java:1055)
        at org.jasypt.encryption.pbe.StandardPBEStringEncryptor.decrypt(StandardPBEStringEncryptor.java:725)
        at org.jasypt.util.text.BasicTextEncryptor.decrypt(BasicTextEncryptor.java:112)
        at com.example.myapplication.MainActivity.start2(MainActivity.java:59)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372) 
        at androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatViewInflater$DeclaredOnClickListener.onClick(AppCompatViewInflater.java:397) 
        at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:4756) 
        at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:19749) 
        at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:739) 
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95) 
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:135) 
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5221) 
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372) 
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:899) 
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:694)
```

///

Вообщем ситуация следующая: Я использую шифратор/дешифратор представим  ситуацию где
я ранее зашифровал   строку и она нормально расшифровывается. Но стоит  мне  удалить или добавить  символы в строку  как тут же - программа падает потому ,что ключ расшифровки уже не подходит
(получается что для этой строки нужен другой ключ  ).

Как сделать чтобы когда программа не может расшифровать строку и за ключа программа выводила , что то типа не верный ключ .

///

```
 implementation group: 'org.jasypt', name: 'jasypt', version: '1.9.2'
```

///

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {


    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);


    }

    public  void start2 (View view)
    {

        BasicTextEncryptor textEncryptor = new BasicTextEncryptor();
        textEncryptor.setPassword("123");

        EditText el2 = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editText2);
        String input = el2.getText().toString();

        String myDecryptedText = textEncryptor.decrypt(input);

        EditText el3 = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editText3);
        el3.setText(myDecryptedText);


    }

}
```

Comment: try catch не подходят?

Comment: «программа падает» — вот этот момент распишите как можно подробнее, по шагам, буквально указывая какие ошибки возникают в программе.

Comment: Добавьте в вопрос ошибку и код, на котором эта ошибка возникает. Желательно проверить "неподходимость" ключа через условие, но можно просто обернуть в `try` опасный блок кода.

Answer (score 1):

Спасибо всем кто сказал про try catch

работает для меня

```
  try {
                String myDecryptedText = textEncryptor.decrypt(input);
                el3.setText(myDecryptedText);
            } catch (Throwable t) {}
        }
```

Comment: Это конечно хорошо, но мне кажется, лучше делать разную обработку разных ошибок (если это конечно требуется). А этим кодом вы перехватываете все исключения и игнорируете это.